# Recommended way to configure pipeline to build and test solution with multiple projects using different frameworks?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

We have a long lived solution developed over many years consisting of multiple projects targeting multiple different frameworks. The solution was originally only targeting .NET Framework (currently 4.8) but have evolved since it's undergoing a migration process (Strangler Fig Pattern). Part for part is modernized by transforming the original application into new projects targeting .NET Standard 2.0 and .NETx. The solution-image showcases a minimal subset of the projects but contains all details regarding target frameworks.

[image]

Everything resides in a single repository in Azure and Azure Pipelines are used to build and test the solution. Everything has been working as expected; all projects build, and all tests are executed, although we've only been running .NET Framework 4.8 tests. Recently we've included the Test Projects for .NETx and .NET Standard 2.0 and they build and tests run as expected locally on development machines.

However, when added to the Azure Pipeline, some weird behavior occurred indicating that the pipeline needs better configuration to work properly. Everything builds as expected but when `VSTest@2` executes we get the error:

```
##[error]An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://mstestadapter/v2': Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
##[error]Stack trace:
##[error]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.TestDeployment.GetDeploymentInformation(String source)
##[error]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.Execution.TestExecutionManager.ExecuteTestsInSource(IEnumerable`1 tests, IRunContext runContext, IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle, String source, Boolean isDeploymentDone)
...
```

After debugging the pipeline we've come to the conclusion that is was the addition of `Playwright` to `TestProject C2` that caused this and removing it would allow tests to run properly. After some more research we've concluded that no top-level packages or transitive packages reference `System.Runtime 6.0.0` but there are a few references to `System.Runtime 4.3.1`. Should add that we've taken steps to make sure that NuGet packages are updated and different projects all target the same versions. Below is our current, pretty basic pipeline with some minor redactons:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - develop
  paths:
    exclude:
    - '*.yml'
    - '*.yaml'

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: 'nuget.config'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: "Tests"
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*projectA2.dll
      **\*projectB2.dll            
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    runTestsInIsolation: true
    codeCoverageEnabled: false
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Naturally we would like to resolve this and configure a pipeline that will allow us to build the whole solution and execute tests targeting all mentioned frameworks, including running `PlayWright` for Blazor. How would such a pipeline be configured? As a side note, in the future we also plan to package and deploy using the pipeline.

Comment: Any luck/update on this?

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that the framework is not available in the machine. Could you try to add this task?

```
 task: UseDotNet@2
   inputs:
     packageType: 'sdk'
     version: '6.x'
```